# Should i set cookie with JavaScript or with a server-side language?

Tags: javascript, cookies, server-side

I know some people disable JavaScript with NoScript add-on so their browser can't run any scripts. Accordingly i won't set cookies. So should i avoid the Javascript way?

Is there have prefered way to set cookies? Is there any exceptions to the rules? Or there have no rules it all?

Comment: For what are you setting cookies? And why would you want to do it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

If the setting of the cookie is related to JavaScript, then use the JavaScript way. For everything else have the server set them.

However, you could use `localStorage` to replace those "JavaScript cookies", if there is no need for the server to know about them.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should use server side technology since it also becomes easier to encrypt the contents of the cookie.

Comment: Is that the best reason you can come up with?